# Insert data in enum() field

Tags: mysql, enums, laravel-5

I am trying to insert data through postman. My error is like below

```
"SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'salutation' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `students` (`salutation`, `fullName`, `nickname`, `studentId`, `email`, `DOB`, `maritalStatus`, `gender`, `blood_group`, `nationality`, `religion`, `mobileNumber`, `homePhone`, `officePhone`, `emergencyContactNumber`, `present_address`, `permanent_address`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (`Mr.`, mouse, hello, laptop, hello, 10/12/2001, Single, Male, A+(ve), dsfsd, 10, mobile, key, 123456, royak, m10, 10, 2019-05-30 10:09:16, 2019-05-30 10:09:16))"
```

My enum() field is like below

[image]

Comment: You have backticks around the value you are trying to insert, which should be single quotes. All your other strings and date values should be enclosed in single quotes too.

Comment: @Nick, Single Quote `SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'salutation' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `students` (`salutation`, `fullName`, `nickname`, `studentId`, `email`, `DOB`, `maritalStatus`, `gender`, `blood_group`, `nationality`, `religion`, `mobileNumber`, `homePhone`, `officePhone`, `emergencyContactNumber`, `present_address`, `permanent_address`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('Mr.', 'mouse', ' hello', 'laptop', 'hello', '10/12/2001', 'Single', 'Male', 'A+(ve)', 'dsfsd', 10, 'mobile', 'key', 123456, 'royak', 'm10', 10, 2019-05-30 10:52:33, 2019-05-30 10:52:33))`

Comment: Works fine for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=656078aa31400fd3ecc9942122fe2b78